# Couldn't update a String variable from onchange on flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm pretty new to flutter and i was trying to update the String *newTask* to the value in the textfield but it keeps resetting it to null.

```
class AddTask extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String newTask;
    return Container(
      color: Color(0xff757575),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:20.0,horizontal: 40.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),topRight: Radius.circular(20.0)),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Add Task',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0,color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
            TextField(
              onChanged:(value){
                newTask = value;                
              },
              autofocus: true,),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Add Task'),
              onPressed: (){
                print(newTask);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I can't seem to see your issue, I ran your code and when I press the button it prints what the value is, can u please elaborate?

Comment: It keeps printing out `null` when i press add task

Answer (score 0):

please use below in `onChanged` event of TextField..

```
 TextField(
          onChanged:(value){
            newTask = value;                
          },
          autofocus: true,),
```

according to me this is correct I also run this code and its return right value.

Comment: You can't use `setState` in a stateless widget.

Comment: Okay I forgot to see

Comment: When you will get null value please tell me the exzat senario

Answer (score 0):

Solved it....i was pressing done on the keyboard then pressing add task...turns out it resets the `newTask` value when you press done on the keyboard...works fine when i press Add task directly after input.